# Why is it not possible to have await operator in the constructor?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, constructor, async-await

Just tried to call an async method with await property in the constructor, causing trouble:

```
  public  MainPage()
    {

        view = new View();
        FacebookApiHandler FacebookApiHandler = new FacebookApiHandler(view);
        await FacebookApiHandler.getAccessByLogin();
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
```

So my 2 questions:

- Why is it not possible to use an await call in the cunstructor?
- Where else should the call be made?

Comment: I have a [blog post on `async` constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) that illustrates several options.

Comment: @StephenCleary I'll take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, if you are working with some kind of UI control as it appears you are, if you have some async work that needs to be done you can put it in the `Loaded` event or some other similar equivalent.

Another option is you start the asynchronous action in the constructor and keep a reference in a `Task` then in your method that needs that async work you perform your `await` there. If the task was not done it returns to the caller to be awaited and it the task was done it just continues synchronously.

The reason you can not `await` in a constructor is the object the constructor is building must be ready to be assigned at the end of the constructor, they did not want to allow you to have a "half finished" object because you would then need a way to track if it was fully complete.

If you really need the class in the constructor one last work around is you have a static factory method make your object. This really is just hiding a implementation of option #2.

```
public MainPage : Page
{
    protected  MainPage()
    {
        view = new View();
        _initTask = Init()
    }

    private async Task Init()
    {
        FacebookApiHandler FacebookApiHandler = new FacebookApiHandler(view);
        await FacebookApiHandler.getAccessByLogin();
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Task _initTask.

    public static Task<MainPage> CreatePageAsync()
    {
         var page = new MainPage();
         await page._initTask;
         return page;
    }
}

//Elsewhere
private async Task MyCode()
{
     MainPage page = await MainPage.CreatePageAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are supposed to *immediately* create an object. By using `await`, it is not certain when the operation will finish. It is not even certain that it will finish at all.

You class seems to be a GUI page. These normally have an event like `Initialized`. You should put your asynchronous code there.